# Ubuntu 14.04 libc.a file format not recognized

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, compiling, gcc, glibc

When I try to compile a simple `.c` file with gcc I always get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

I tried to reinstall gcc but this had no effect

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem myself by reinstalling related packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc libc6 libc6-dev
```